# Remove public/index.php from url in Lavarel App

Tags: php, laravel, apache, ubuntu-18.04

Created my first Laravel App (Using Lavarel 7.x) on Ubuntu 18.04LTS with Apache2 on a local PC I have.

Followed setup intstruction from [Lavarel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation), all went well.
One issue is with the url:

```
http://localhost/lavarel-project1/ - returns the directory listing
```

The apache2 virtual host file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/lavarel-project1/public

   <Directory /var/www/html/lavarel-project1/public>
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
   </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

From researching on the web - articles stated to copy server.php file from Lavarel App root directory and rename it index.php.
This worked but then created routes in the app, found other issues with the url:

```
http://localhost/lavarel-project1/ - works
http://localhost/lavarel-project1/catlog/ - doesn't work
http://localhost/lavarel-project1/public/index.php/catlog - works
```

Here is the content of the .htaccess file in the public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
      Options -MultiViews -Indexes
  </IfModule>

  RewriteEngine On

  # Handle Authorization Header
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
  RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

  # Send Requests To Front Controller...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Researched this issue on the web - how to go about removing public/index.php from the url, but with little success - all methods recommended don't work, hence asking the question on here.
 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to enable mod_rewrite ? ```sudo a2enmod rewrite``` and then restart apache: ```sudo systemctl restart apache2``` ; my second question would be, do you have a .htaccess file in your public folder?

Comment: @forloops, thanks for helping. I have done that enabled mod_write on apache2 and restart it. Still have the issue. Yes, I do have one (.htaccess file) in the public folder on the lavarel App. I will add the content to question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not put '/public' at Directory tag.

Try this:

`
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/lavarel-project1/public

```
<Directory /var/www/html/lavarel-project1>
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

`

This is my configuration and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>

 ServerName laravel.dev
 ServerAlias www.laravel.dev
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/lavarel-project1/public
 
    <Directory /var/www/html/lavarel-project1/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
 
LogLevel debug
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```